# new HiveConf() does not load hive-site.xml

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos

I want to access values from hive-site.xml in my hadoop ToolRunner class (namely to acquire hive delegation token).

But when I do `new HiveConf()` or `new HiveConf(configuration, HiveConf.class)` the created HiveConf contains just defaults and none of the settings from hive-site.xml

I have found mentions that the solution should be to add /etc/hive/conf to the HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env.sh, but this did not fix the loading of the config values and led to an exception when trying to get a JDBC HiveConnection.

```java
Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has not been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:283)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:247)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.<init>(NucleusContext.java:225)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.<init>(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:416)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:202)
```

Which almost seems like more hive code is required on the classpath but missing.

What is the correct way of finding out the HiveServer2 address and other settings?

Comment: Long story short: add `/etc/hive/conf` (the directory) to the effective CLASSPATH. All Hadoop components search for directories in CLASSPATH then search these for their config files (with hard-coded names) ; 1st match wins.

Comment: And anyway this will not solve your problem because **the JDBC driver does not care for `HiveConf`** -- it connects directly to HiveServer2 with Thrift wire protocol (just like Python or C# programs would). All connection params must be passed in the JDBC URL, read the docs.

Comment: And the JDBC driver can manage the Kerberos auth automagically, no need to pre-fetch a token (unless you go through a proxy account such as `oozie` or `hue` services).

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter thanks for the inputs - I am not comfortable to add stuff to CLASSPATH global env variable, have not seen any doc that would suggest that. Unfortunatelly you are not correct the JDBC driver does not generate delegation tokens automagically, at least not to my knowledge and actual experiments.

Comment: I never said that the JDBC driver would manage _Hadoop delegation tokens_. It does not give a shit about tokens. It just needs **pure Kerberos auth** at connection time.

Comment: Tokens are only useful if **A.** you have multiple clients _(e.g. Spark executors)_ and/or multiple servers _(e.g. HDFS DataNodes)_ and point-to-point Kerberos auth is inefficient; or **B.** if your client(s) cannot get a local Kerberos ticket _(e.g. Spark running in YARN containers, or a Java app launched by Oozie scheduler)_. But the way I understand it, you have a custom Java app connecting to a single HiveServer2 instance, and the app has a local Kerberos ticket. So why bother about tokens??

Comment: If you really want to get a token for Hive Metastore and/or HiveServer2, you should inspect the Oozie source code about "credentials" (types `hcat` and `hive2` if I'm not mistaken) to see how they are obtained. Or the Spark source code (the "client" component that is started first and bootstraps the driver -- was refactored in V2.2 if I remember well). But that's not what your question was about...